# Add New column with constant value in SuperSet

Tags: apache-superset

I'm looking to add a column with a default value in superset.

All rows will be filled with the value "ABC".

Are there anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just use single `'`.

```
SELECT *,
       'ABC' as "new_column"
FROM BDD
```